# Js broken in Backend M2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have some problem on my online store with Magento 2.2.2

After enable merge Js in Magento Backend:

Store/Configuration/Advanced/Developer and save the config. I realized that I can't click any menu button in the backend. Js is broken so I can't go to Merge Js config and disable it again.

How can I fix this bug? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go to database of Magento 2 site, run this SQL command:
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%dev%'
Change 'dev/js/merge_files' to '0'
Then run deploy theme command with SSH to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

After enabling merge you need to **redeploy static content**, because magento doesn't merge them on the fly.
Also if you are enabling merge - enable js bunling too. But latter is working **only on production** mode.